# ASN.1 Sequence Confusion

Tags: asn.1

I'm studying the syntax for [**ASN.1**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asn.1), and I've read a lot of the relevant material online:

http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.690-200811-I/en

http://luca.ntop.org/Teaching/Appunti/asn1.html 

http://www.obj-sys.com/asn1tutorial/node11.html

I'm very confused over the encoding of ASN.1 `SEQUENCE` types.  In general, I realize that a `SEQUENCE` is basically an aggregate - what we'd call an OBJECT or an INSTANCE in most programming languages.  It's basically a list of name/value pairs, similar to a JSON object.  But unlike a JSON object, an ASN.1 `SEQUENCE` has an implicit SCHEMA, because it is an *instance of a "class"*.

So, the class/schema for a `SEQUENCE` might be something like:

```
{
  name  UTF8String
  age   INTEGER
}
```

And an *INSTANCE* of that schema could be the `SEQUENCE`

```
{
  "John Smith"
  42
}
```

But I'm totally confused as to how you can tell the difference between a CLASS and an INSTANCE in the actual BER encoding.  In fact, I'm so confused, I'm not even sure if a ASN.1 `SEQUENCE` is supposed to be a class definition or an instance of a class.

The documentation seems to imply it's an instance:

> **8.9** Encoding of a sequence value
>
> **8.9.1** The encoding of a sequence value shall be constructed.
>
> **8.9.2** The contents octets shall consist of the complete encoding of one data value from each of the types listed in the ASN.1 definition
>   of the sequence type, in the order of their appearance in the
>   definition, unless the type was referenced with the keyword OPTIONAL
>   or the keyword DEFAULT.
>
> **8.9.3** The encoding of a data value may, but need not, be present for a type which was referenced with the keyword OPTIONAL or the keyword
>   DEFAULT. If present, it shall appear in the encoding at the point
>   corresponding to the appearance of the type in the ASN.1 definition.

So it seems a SEQUENCE is just a list of data values, which must correspond to some schema (class).  But ASN.1 doesn't have a `CLASS` type, so how do you get the actual class, so you know what class any given SEQUENCE is an instance of?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you write the following:

```
R DEFINITIONS AUTOMATIC TAGS ::=

 BEGIN

 USPostalAddress ::= SEQUENCE {

      street     IA5String,

      city       IA5String,

      state      IA5String (SIZE (2)) (FROM("A".."Z")),

      zipcode    IA5String (SIZE (5)) (FROM("0".."9"))

 }

 END
```

The part between BEGIN and END above is called a "type assignment".  "USPostalAddress" is the name of a (user-defined) "type".  By writing the above, you have specified a user-defined type and you have given a name to it.  Each SEQUENCE construct (the above SEQUENCE construct, for example) is a "type". It's a complex type, in that it contains one or more "fields" each having its own type. A possible "value" of the above type is denoted as follows:

```
{ street "1234 Main St.", city "New York", state "NY", zipcode "12345" }
```

We are just talking about types and their values, not about classes and instances. Just like you can have a type  INTEGER (0..15)  whose values are integer numbers between 0 and 15, you can have a SEQUENCE type whose values are arrangements of lower-level values. The above sequence type is a very simple example of the data structures ("types") you can define in ASN.1.

(In ASN.1 there is also something called a "class" but it's a completely different thing.)

In ASN.1, messages of protocols are usually specified as top-level types (usually they are SEQUENCE or CHOICE types). A particular "message value" is a value of a top-level type.  When you have a value of a top-level type in your hands, you can encode that value into a stream of bits by using one of the standard encoding rules (BER, PER, etc.).  When you receive a stream of bits from the network which you know was a value of a particular ASN.1 type encoded in BER, PER, etc., you can decode those bits and obtain the original value.

Answer (score 1):

ASN.1 file contains usually type assignments (type definitions) like this SEQUENCE type:

```
myMessage ::= SEQUENCE
{
    a INTEGER(0..100),
    b INTEGER
}
```

Those SEQUENCE types inside ASN.1 file can be considered same as classes in C++/java or struct definitions in C.

Instances of SEQUENCE can be in encoded format (BER, PER, DER etc) or in local format (objects/variables) inside your programs.

Example how you could implement those in C code:

```
struct myMessage_t          
{
  int a;
  int b;
};

char buffer[1000];   // BER encoded instance will be stored to this buffer
myMessage_t msg;     // this is the local instance

msg.a = 1;
msg.b = 2;

size_t berLen = berEncode_myMessage( &msg, buffer, sizeof(buffer) );
```

And decoding side for that:

```
myMessage_t msg2;            
berDecode_myMessage( buffer, berLen, &msg2 );
assert( msg2.a == 1 );
```

You usually know what is the top level type of encoded instance, before you decode it.